# Input stream syntax

Tags: java

I am practicing my coding skills on code chef and a line of code in java has perplexed me.
Can someone explain it in a simple way.

```
InputStream inputStream = System.in;
```

This syntax of input stream, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: `in` is a member variable of class `System`, and the type of that variable is `InputStream`, so you can assign it to another variable of type `InputStream`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why system.in is used. Usually  a path is present here.

Comment: From just that line of code, it's impossible to tell why it was written like that. It depends on the context (what does the program that contains this line do, what was the intent of the programmer etc.). `System.in` is an input stream that reads from the console or terminal.

Comment: [`System` (specifically `java.lang.System`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html) is a class. [`in` is a public static field of that class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in). It is of type `InputStream`. So your statement isn't much different than `String s = "abc";`: you're simply assigning a value of a type to a variable of the same type. Nothing specific to `InputStream` is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a clearer way for now you must know that inputStream is a class where one of its usefull functions to get input of data from user maybe or any other place so for that you create an instance of this class

```
InputStream inputStream
```

and then you initiate this input by "where i should get the input of data?" so
`= System.in;` means i want to get input from system (example : keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are reading keyboard input(Standard input stream), then usually you do:

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Here, Scanner constructor is accepting `java.io.InputStream` parameter which `System.in` is returning.

`in` is public static member variable of `System` class of type `java.io.InputStream`.